# preposition or conjunction?

Tags: prepositions

Children with lower IQs were more persistent and resilient even when faced with frustrations, and they practiced **until** bettering their abilities and becoming better chess players than those with higher IQs.

Is the "until" a conjunction or preposition in the sentence? It looks like "prep + gerund" to me. if not, can u tell me why it cannot be a preposition?

Comment: Then how is the tag "preposition"?

Answer (score 1):

> Children with lower IQs were more persistent and resilient even when faced with frustrations, and they practiced **until** bettering their abilities and becoming better chess players than those with higher IQs.

*Until* in this sentence is a preposition. It stands for *up to* the point in time or the event mentioned, i.e., "bettering their abilities."

Comment: I asked the same on another site, and the answer is as follows:

Comment: I would class that sentence as somewhat ungrammatical (it should read “until they had bettered … and become …”). The book as a whole appears to have been inadequately edited, or maybe translated: Homo Sapiens But Dumber

When used as a preposition, the word until is followed by a noun/noun phrase: 
The doors don’t open until 6 pm / He didn’t find out until the next day / They played outside until dark​

When used as a conjunction, it is followed by a clause (with subject and verb):
They kept practising until they got better at it / No computer games until you’ve done your homework!​

Comment: The use of *bettering* here is to imply "having bettered" -- it's a common enough structure and the author seems to have got it all right.